# How to use Gmail API in php?

Tags: php, laravel, api, gmail-api, guzzle

I have been able to obtain access token and refresh token on gmail login and been able to use their [list](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages/list) emails API successfully.

I checked out their documentation on how to use their [send](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages/send) and also [get](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages/get) email APIs. But i am not getting more resources anywhere and would be helpful if there is any useful resource for this.

Any clear example and documentation for php guzzle on which parameters and how to pass when using the send and get APIs.

```
    public function emailSend($access_token,$data,$email_address,$attach_status)
{
    $data = rtrim(strtr(base64_encode($data), '+/', '-_'), '=');
    $client = new Client();
    $URI ='https://gmail.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/'.$email_address.'/messages/send';
    if($attach_status==1){
        $URI ='https://gmail.googleapis.com/upload/gmail/v1/users/'.$email_address.'/messages/send';
    }
    $params['headers'] = ['Content-type' => 'application/json','Accept' => 'application/json','Authorization' => 'Bearer '.$access_token];
    $params['form_params'] = array(
        'raw' => $data,
    );
    $response = $client->request('POST',$URI, $params);
    $object = json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents(), true);
    return $object;
}
```

How to implement this?

Thank You.

Comment: The docs look pretty clear to me. What code are you trying?

Comment: Thank you for responding.Added code in my question now.What to pass as parameters and how?

Comment: Assuming you are using the Guzzle client you need to use [`json`](https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html#json) instead of `form_params` and to send a message object (described [here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages#Message)). You can pass it as a PHP associative array. Do not wrap it in `raw` or do any base64 encoding.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Send email from PHP site through GMAIL API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51807161/send-email-from-php-site-through-gmail-api)

Comment: If your not using the google api php client library then your not following their documentaiton.

Comment: @DaImTo that's not true. The linked documentation is their REST documentation so would work with any REST client. Using the google api php client ([this one](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/gmail/v1/php/latest/)) is convinent but not strictly necessary

Comment: Google is going to most often give you language based samples using their client libraries.  Doing pure rest is a waste of your time and prone to errors its the point of having a client library.

Comment: @apokryfos Can you please explain what to pass in json in the message object? Please give an example..thanks

Comment: Well try `$params['json'] => [ 'raw' => $data ]` for starters. You don't need the application/json content-type in this case since guzzle fills it in automatically as well as does the json encoding

Comment: @apokryfos any idea about what to pass in $data?

Comment: It should look like what you get from `messages.get` . If you don't know how to pass a raw message then craft the message using the Message object i.e. with `[ 'payload' => [ MessagePart ] ]` where MessagePart is the object described [here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages#Message.MessagePart)